# Polynomial interpolation with data points from derivative of original polynomial

Tags: polynomials, numerical-methods, interpolation, cubics, lagrange-interpolation

Question:
What is a polynomial g(x) no more than degree 3 (including 3) s.t. 
$$g(0) = 1, g(1) = 0, g′(0) = 0, g′(−1) = −1$$

Solution is: $$g(x) = −\frac3 5x^3 − \frac2 5x^2 + 1$$

My attempt: I was thinking of setting up the general cubic which has the form $g(x) = ax^3 + bx^2 + cx + d$. Then plugging in the four points given in the function will give me four equations in the four unknowns $\{a,b,c,d\}$. But there is derivatives here. (I barely learned about lagrange interpolation, does that have anythign to do with this problem?)

Comment: Are you sure you wrote the solution correctly? You have a general $g(x)$ and can find $g'(x)$ from that. And then you have four points to solve for the values. Why do you need interpolation?

Comment: the solution is from the textbook so it should be correct and the question is to figure out the g(x) using four data points which is using interpolation i belivev to form a polynomial function

Comment: you cannot find g'(x) if i did not write down the answer at all? so i dont see your point

Comment: Books make mistakes all the time. $$g'(x) = 3 a x^2 + 2 bx + c$$ You have two values for $g(x)$ and two values for $g'(x)$, now use them!

Comment: please excuse my mistake i wrote down the answer wrong; your question was a little confusing so i was confused

Answer (score 1):

We have

$$g(x) = ax^3 + bx^2 + c x + d \implies g'(x) = 3ax^2 + 2bx + c$$

We also have

$$g(0) = a (0) + b(0) + c(0) + d = 1 \implies d = 1$$

Can you continue?

Find $g(1), g'(0), g'(-1)$ and solve for the last three constants.

Comment: so this has nothign to do with interpolation? because the whole chapter was on interpolation\

Comment: What book are you using?

Comment: numerical mathematics and computing 7th edition chapter 4.1 which is on interpolation using newton, lagrange etc so I was just wondering if using interpolation is possible ( it is a new concept for me) thanks again

Comment: It is possible they want you to figure out using some combination of divided differences and interpolation formulas, but that is too cumbersome. I suppose another approach is to take the Lagrange polynomial and it's derivative and work this backward.

Comment: can you please explain the lagrange and backward part in a little more detail if you have time? im studying this practice question for my quiz